# numpy: Setting values to zero based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an RGB image and I am trying to perform a simple thresholding for it using something like this:

```
from skimage import filter
def threshold(image):
    r = image[:, :, 0]
    g = image[:, :, 1]
    b = image[:, :, 2]

    rt = filter.threshold_otsu(r)
    gt = filter.threshold_otsu(g)
    bt = filter.threshold_otsu(b)
```

What I would like to do is now make a binary mask where the RGB values in the original image which are less than these threshold value should be set to 0.

```
mask = np.ones(r.shape)
```

What I cannot figure out how to do is how do I set the mask indices (x, y) to zero where the

```
image[x, y, 0] < rt and image[x, y, 1] < gt and image [x, y, 2] < bt
```

Somehow I need to get the (x, y) pixel indices from this original image which meets this criteria but I am not sure how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried using `&` instead of `and`? (the Python `and` doesn't work well with NumPy arrays.)

Comment: I did. It comes with 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). I never quite figured out how to ever resolve this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NumPy's `&` performs `bit-wise and`. When applied to arrays, the `bit-wise and` is applied element-wise. Since the comparisons, e.g. `r < rt`, return boolean arrays, the result of `bit-wise and` here is the same as `logical and`. The parentheses are needed because NumPy's `&` has [higher precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) than `<`.

```
mask = (r < rt) & (g < gt) & (b < bt)
image[mask] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanations as well!

Answer (score 2):

Be careful - OpenCV uses "BGR", not RGB.
so using

```
r = image[:, :, 0]
```

yields the BLUE channel, *NOT* the RED channel!